# Start & Stop HANA Instance with Github Actions

Tags: database, github-actions, cloud-foundry, hana

is there a way to automate HANA DB **start & stop** using **github actions**?

If so, could you show me how to do it?

Thank you all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: where is your HANA instance is hosted: local machine or cloud?